# How can I change the background color of a cell in LyX?

Tags: windows-7, latex, lyx

I have a table in LyX:

[image]

How can I change the background color of one cell, or alternate the background color between rows?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the excellent [colortbl package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) to do this.

Comment: Thanks indeed that's what I use when I edit the code directly, but does LyX provide any GUI way to do it (like it does for text coloring for instance)?

Comment: No UI unfortunately, as its an external package. But isn't that the beauty of LaTeX? Use it a couple of times and you wouldn't care about a GUI :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: [Share this idea](http://www.lyx.org/GetInvolved#toc7) with the LyX team as a feature request.